# Grouping and centering svg's with react

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am trying to create a progress indicator of sorts to show where in a process someone is inside a react application. The end result should look something like this: 
[image]

To do this I am starting by creating a component for the circle with step number and label below it using svg's but my problem is that I can't figure out how to center the label text without it being clipped. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import colors from '../../stylesheets/colors';

const ProgressNode = (props) => {
  const {
  width = 4,
  radius = 60,
  color = colors.DISABLED,
  text = '1',
  textColor = colors.DISABLED,
  fontSize = radius - 5,
  label = 'Confirm Location',
} = props;

// subtract stroke width from radius to avoid clipping
const r = radius - (width * 2);

return (
  <div style={{ margin: 100, border:'2px solid red'}}>
    <svg
      height={radius * 4}
      width={radius * 4}
    >
      <svg
        height={radius * 2}
        width={radius * 2}
        cx={radius}
        cy={radius}
      >
        <circle
          fill="transparent"
          strokeWidth={width}
          r={r}
          cx={radius}
          cy={radius}
          stroke={color}
        />
        <text
          x="50%"
          y="50%"
          textAnchor="middle"
          stroke={textColor}
          strokeWidth={width - 1}
          fontSize={fontSize}
          fill={textColor}
          // dy=".3em"
        >
          <tspan x="50%" dy=".3em">{text}</tspan>
          <tspan x="50%" dy="1.8em">{label}</tspan>
        </text>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </div>
);
};

export default ProgressNode;
```

The problem is that the label text is being clipped

[image]

Does anyone know how I can center the label text under the circle and if you have any ideas how to arrange the nodes and lines that would be a bonus :)

Comment: As long as the positioning is correct, it might suffice to set `svg { overflow: visible; }` in CSS.